# Run python script before gatsby build

Tags: javascript, python, gatsby

Is there a way to configure Gatsbyjs so that a python script runs before anything else gets build in Gatsby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use npm you can use [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to run arbitrary scripts before and after common npm commands.

In your case you could probably do something like that (not tested):

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "python main.py",
    "start": "gatsby"
 },
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the "pre-" prefix with npm.